# .NET Core - join 2 tables with AsQueryable

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have two nested classes: Partner contains a Company (that has a field "Name")

- I do a search by Id on the partner's Id
- I want to do a search on the company's "Name" field

here is my poco:

```
public class Partner
{
    [Required]
    public int? Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Company Company { get; set; }
```

using **AsQueryable**, I can then stack filters one by one

I try to have a query that joins the second table to do a search on that entity's name field

```
public DbSet<Partner> Partners { get; set; }

...

var data = _context.Partners.AsQueryable();

if (partnersSearch.SearchById != null)
{
     data = data.Where(p => p.Id == partnersSearch.SearchById.GetValueOrDefault());
}
if (partnersSearch.SearchByName != null)
{
     data = data.Include(a => a.Company.Select(b => b.Name = partnersSearch.SearchByName));
```

but for the join between the tables, the **last line cannot compile**

it complains that **Company does not contain a definition of has no Select**

what am I doing wrong ?

thanks for helping me on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try a where after your include. Does that help?

`data.Include(a => a.Company).Where(partner=>partner.Company.Name.equals(partnersSearch.SearchByName))`

Comment: it does not return anything...I also tried data = data.Where(p => p.Company.Name.Equals(partnersSearch.SearchByName));...no data is returned

Comment: ok it works, I had another include below and I was not typing the whole name, I'll have to mod it to be more flexible

Comment: actually do you know how to check if the field contains the string (case insensitive) ? I get linq errors